# aligned arrays of length zero in struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct

```
struct net_buf_simple {
    /** Pointer to the start of data in the buffer. */
    u8_t *data;
    /** Length of the data behind the data pointer. */
    u16_t len;
    /** Amount of data that this buffer can store. */
    u16_t size;
    u8_t __buf[0] __attribute__ ((aligned(4)));
    /** Start of the data storage. Not to be accessed directly
     *  (the data pointer should be used instead).
     */
};

int main()
{
    struct net_buf_simple buf_a;
    uint8_t array[4];
    buf_a.data = array;
    
    printf("buf_a:%p, data:%p, len:%p, size:%p, __buf:%p  sizeof(int):%d\n",  &buf_a, buf_a.data, &buf_a.len, &buf_a.size, buf_a.__buf, sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}

buf_a:0x7ffc7a0f7930, data:0x555cd091e740, len:0x7ffc7a0f7938, size:0x7ffc7a0f793a, __buf:0x7ffc7a0f793c  sizeof(int):4
```

I'm confused about the print address: there are 2 bytes before buf_a.len? The address buf_a.data is at the end of the struct? Shouldn't the __buf[0] point to the buf_a.data directly?

Comment: Variables don't have to be stored in the same order that they're declared, and there can be padding between the variables.

Comment: Why would you expect the address of `__buf` to be the same as `array`? They're different variables, they shouldn't overlap.

Comment: Flexible array members should only be used with dynamically-allocated memory. Not local structures.

Comment: @Ben Bu Where do you have found "2 bytes before buf_a.len"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I thought members inside struct should be in order with padding

Comment: They are. The beginning of the struct is at `0x7ffc7a0f7930`, `data` takes 8 bytes, then `len` is at `0x7ffc7a0f7938`

Comment: I was talking about the ordering of `buf_a` and `array`. They're not in the same struct.

Comment: If the data point to the array at 0x555cd091e740, and the beginning of 8-byte memory in the struct is not used?

Comment: the library use funtion like this to calculate the head room. I'm confused how it works in this case: size_t net_buf_simple_headroom(struct net_buf_simple *buf)
{
    return buf->data - buf->__buf;
}.

Comment: To use a struct with `__buf` as you have it, you probably want `main` to be something like: `int count = 4; struct net_buf_simple *buf_a = malloc(sizeof(struct net_buf_simple) + count); buf_a->len = count; buf_a->data = buf_a->__buf;` Note that doing: `struct net_buf_simple buf_a; uint8_t array[4];` does _not_ guarantee that `__buf` and `array` share the same address. The compiler is completely free to order the stack any way it wants (e.g.) `array` could have a _lower_ address than `buf_a`

Comment: Got it. why does it use  (aligned(sizeof(int)) for __buf?

Comment: @BenBu Whatever is using the structure probably aliases `__buf` to an `int` pointer.

Comment: As to the `aligned` it has no _functional_ meaning since `__buf` is a `char` array. It might have a [poor] cache alignment speedup. But, as I said, just declaring `buf_a` followed by `array` is _broken_. I actually worked at a company that did that and expected `buf_a` to have a lower address than `array`. It worked ... Until the new rev of the compiler came along and _reversed_ the stack layout (i.e. the code broke and produced UB).

Comment: I did: buf_a->data = buf_a->__buf with  len = 16;  the data address is equal to buf_a. But there still are 8 bytes at the beginning of the struct which is not used?

Comment: The u8_t *data only uses 4 bytes in buf_a.

Comment: @BenBu "talking about the ordering of `buf_a` and `array`" is not defined by C.  `buf_a` might come before `array`, might come after `array`, might have padding between, might exist in separate incompatible address spaces.  Best to avoid this type of code.

Comment: @BenBu  Looks like you want a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

Comment: I removed the array and did struct net_buf_simple *buf_a = malloc(sizeof(struct net_buf_simple) + 16);   the buf_a->data is a pointer and should only take 4 bytes since printf of sizeof(int) is 4. However the &buf_a->len:0x55d23512d268 is 8 bytes after the address of buf_a:0x55d23512d260.

Comment: Also, identifiers starting with two underscores, such as `__buf`, are [reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Unless there is a collision with a `#define` macro name, I don't think that applies to a `struct` member name (If the spec says that it does, I'd love to know the rationale). It's unlikely that a standard name will use `__buf` anyway. On a practical note, I've used `__` for four decades and _never_ (not _once_) had to change anything to avoid a conflict (perhaps because I choose names that are unlikely to collide).

Comment: @CraigEstey  Well, it does say "**All** identifiers ... are **always** reserved for **any** use".  I suspect the intent here is to reserve such identifiers for macros, among other things.  Note that the output of `echo | gcc -dM -E -` is almost entirely macros that start with two underscores. And a quick `find /usr/include -type f | xargs grep '^#define __' | wc -l` returns 3308 on a Centos system I have access to.  Each one of those could potentially cause problems should a `struct` field share the same name.

Comment: A portable C program does not include arrays of size 0. Or structs of size 0. Or any other object of size 0. Any of those things would be Undefined Behaviour. Some compilers accept arrays declared with constant length 0 to be equivalent to flexible array members. Since a flexible array member has incomplete type, applying `sizeof` to it will again produce Undefined Behaviour. In short, this question can only be answered in the context of a specific compiler which implements some extension to standard C, and that specific compiler's documentation needs to be consulted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *no* unaccounted for space at the front of the `struct`.

However, even if we remove the `aligned` on `__buf`, it still does alignment of the `struct` length.

Unless, we add `__attribute__((packed))` to the struct definition.

---

Here is a modified version of your code to produce a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef unsigned char u8_t;
typedef unsigned short u16_t;

typedef struct net_buf_simple {
    /** Pointer to the start of data in the buffer. */
    u8_t *data;

    /** Length of the data behind the data pointer. */
    u16_t len;

    /** Amount of data that this buffer can store. */
    u16_t size;

#if NOALIGN
    u8_t __buf[0];
#else
    u8_t __buf[0] __attribute__ ((aligned(4)));
#endif
    /** Start of the data storage. Not to be accessed directly
     *  (the data pointer should be used instead).
     */
}
#if PACKED
__attribute__((packed))
#endif
bufsimp;

#define SHOWP(_sym) \
    printf("  " #_sym " ptr=%p off=%zu (offsetof %zu, width %zu)\n", \
        bufp->_sym,(char *) bufp->_sym - (char *) bufp, \
        offsetof(bufsimp,_sym),sizeof(bufp->_sym))

#define SHOWI(_sym) \
    printf("  " #_sym " val=%u (offsetof %zu, width %zu)\n", \
        bufp->_sym, \
        offsetof(bufsimp,_sym),sizeof(bufp->_sym))

bufsimp *
newbuf(int cap)
{

    bufsimp *bufp = malloc(sizeof(bufsimp) + cap);

    bufp->data = bufp->__buf;
    bufp->size = cap;
    bufp->len = 0;

    return bufp;
}

void
showbuf(bufsimp *bufp,const char *sym)
{
    printf("showbuf: %s\n",sym);
    printf("  bufp %p\n",bufp);
    SHOWP(data);
    SHOWI(len);
    SHOWI(size);
    SHOWP(__buf);
}

int
main(void)
{

    printf("sizeof=%zu\n",sizeof(bufsimp));

    bufsimp *buf_a = newbuf(4);
    showbuf(buf_a,"buf_a");

#if HAVEB
    bufsimp *buf_b = newbuf(16);
    showbuf(buf_b,"buf_b");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the output of the program compiled normally:

```
sizeof=16
showbuf: buf_a
  bufp 0x21f4270
  data ptr=0x21f427c off=12 (offsetof 0, width 8)
  len val=0 (offsetof 8, width 2)
  size val=4 (offsetof 10, width 2)
  __buf ptr=0x21f427c off=12 (offsetof 12, width 0)
```

---

Here is the output with `-DNOALIGN`:

```
sizeof=16
showbuf: buf_a
  bufp 0x16e1270
  data ptr=0x16e127c off=12 (offsetof 0, width 8)
  len val=0 (offsetof 8, width 2)
  size val=4 (offsetof 10, width 2)
  __buf ptr=0x16e127c off=12 (offsetof 12, width 0)
```

---

Here is the output with: `-DNOALIGN -DPACKED`:

```
sizeof=12
showbuf: buf_a
  bufp 0xd09270
  data ptr=0xd0927c off=12 (offsetof 0, width 8)
  len val=0 (offsetof 8, width 2)
  size val=4 (offsetof 10, width 2)
  __buf ptr=0xd0927c off=12 (offsetof 12, width 0)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! Feels very comfortable reading your code.